# Hide primeng carousel navigation buttons

Tags: html, angular, primeng

In PrimeNg Documentation says that I can hide navigations buttons by property 'showNavigators', but when I bind in carousel nothing happens.

```
                <p-carousel [value]="product.imageUrls" [showNavigators]="false" [style]="{'min-height':'300px', 'max-height':'300px'}">    
                    <ng-template let-image pTemplate="item">
                        <img [src]="image">
                    </ng-template>
                </p-carousel>
```

What I doing wrong or maybe has another way to hide navigation buttons?

Comment: which version of primeng, you are using? latest 12?

Comment: angular version is 11.1.1 . PrimeNg version 11.4.3

Comment: It is working fine. https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-carousel-demo-ew2jbr?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: I don't see any issue with above stackblitz demo, Can you recheck again your code?

Comment: Yes, it works. I think the problem was with my browser. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

[showNavigators]="false"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because you have an older release of your PrimeNG in your code, but you're looking at the current documentation.

You can hide them with CSS:

```
:host ::ng-deep p-carousel {
  //On later realease of PrimeNG, this can be done programmatically with [showIndicators | showNavigators]="false"
  .p-carousel-indicators {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .p-carousel-next, .p-carousel-prev {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```